# Excel VBA - Insert chart from dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a vba application that creates a new sheet and inserts a variable number of values into the first two columns below a header (column A and B will always have a corresponding value, I just don't know how many rows there will be):

[image: Example]

I'd like to use vba to embed a simple bar graph a few columns over in the same sheet that looks kind of like this:

[image: Example 2]

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? I've tried a bunch of examples but can't seem to get the formatting correct due to the range always being variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic setup I use.  You can add a lot of formatting to add data labels, remove gridlines, change the title, etc.  You may consider learning about defining ranges before going much further in VBA.

```
Sub AddGraphs()

    'Set the dynamic ranges
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Create the chart
    Charts.Add
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, LC))
        .Location xlLocationAsObject, "Sheet1"
    End With

    'Format chart and set location
    With ActiveChart
        .Parent.Top = Cells(1, LC + 3).Top
        .Parent.Left = Cells(1, LC + 3).Left
        .HasLegend = False
    End With

End Sub
```